# Convert the following to Python List Comprehension

Tags: python, python-2.7, list-comprehension

Do you think the following code can be converted to list comprehension?
I am having a difficult time to come up with the solution.

```
   curr_page = 10
   l_count = 0
   for x in range(current_page-1, 0, -1): 
        if l_count <= 9: 
            page_list.insert(0, x)
            l_count = l_count + 1
        if l_count >= 9:
            x = 0
```

Comment: should `curr_page` and `current_page` be the same? Can you write it as a function wiith arguments so we can see which bits are inputs, and which bits are implementation?

Comment: `l_count` your indicator but after 9 value will not work.

Answer (score 2):

Without any further information, the list "comprehension" is just `page_list = range(1, 10)`.

Speculatively, you may even want:

- `range(1, curr_page)`
- `range(max(0, curr_page - 9), curr_page)`

Answer (score 0):

```
page_list = []
current_page = 10
l_count = 0
for x in range(current_page-1, 0, -1):
    if l_count <= 9:
        page_list.insert(0, x)
        l_count = l_count + 1
    if l_count >= 9:
        x = 0

print page_list
```

Outputs

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Therefore it can be simplified to

```
page_list = range(1,10)
```

If you really want list comprehension

```
page_list = [x for x in range(1,10)]
```